# Sort two dimensional list containing True/False

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays containing `True/False`. I want to order them by which one has the least `False`. How should I attempt to sort them.

My first thought was to put every the second dimension array into a dict and add a key containing the amount of False in the array. And sort them based on that. Something Like this:

```
{"value": 1, "array": [true, true, false]}
```

But this seems a little cumbersome to me. So is there a way to optimize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sorted` with a `key` argument for the number of `False` in each list.

```
>>> sorted([[False, False, False], [False, True, True], [False, False, True]], key=lambda x: x.count(False))
[[False, True, True], [False, False, True], [False, False, False]]
```

Comment: I like this one best, i was going for what Ankur did, but i think this is cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, they're similar, but I think a direct count is more readable.

Comment: More readable and generalises to other values much easier.

Comment: I agree. Using `.count()` is much better.

Comment: Thanks, far better way than I thought

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```py
array_or_arrays = [
    [True, True, False, True],
    [True, True, True, True],
    [True, False, False, True],
    [False, False, False, False]
]

sorted(array_or_arrays, key=lambda array: len(array) - sum(array), reverse=True)
[[False, False, False, False],
 [True, False, False, True],
 [True, True, False, True],
 [True, True, True, True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple lambda solution:

```
input_array = [[False,False],[False],[],[False,False,False]]
output_array = sorted(array, key=lambda x: x.count(False))
# output: [[], [False], [False, False], [False, False, False]]
```